# Django rest_framework: How to pass additional attribute to exception / error response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Python 3.6 with Django 1.11.9 and rest_framework 3.6.2.

I have a view (APIView) which can only be accessed by some users who successfully pass a given HasUnlimitedAccesPermission check. In case of failure to pass the latter, I raise a PermissionDenied with a detailed message of my choice about the error to pass on to front-end. So far so good, all of that is easily achievable by applying the HasUnlimitedAccessPermission to my view thanks to the "permission_classes" decorator (yeah, I'm using a function_based view, here).

Now, what I would like to achieve is passing an additional attribute to my  error response JSON (when the user fails to pass the permission test). This attribute would be an "error_id" attribute that would give the front-end developer the ability to adapt the error display depending on the "error_id" value. An example of the response JSON would be :

```
{
    "error": "To enjoy this feature, go pick one of our pay offer!",
    "error_id": "no_unlimited_access"
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: looks like you need http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

Comment: This might help - https://github.com/FutureMind/drf-friendly-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to Bear Brown's comment and Jerin Peter George's answer (completed by rest_framework source code), I've done as follows:

1) Created a custom PermissionDenied exception:

```
class CustomPermissionDenied(PermissionDenied):

    def __init__(self, detail=None, code=None, error_id=None):
        super().__init__(detail=detail, code=code)
        self.error_id = error_id
```

which is raised in HasUnlimitedAccessPermission, for instance, this way:

```
raise CustomPermissionDenied(detail=_("To use this feature, subscribe to one of our plans."),
                             error_id="no_unlimited_access")
```

2) In a custom_exception_handler (that I already had for other purpose) I added the lines between the ellipses

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    ...
    error_id = getattr(exc, "error_id", None)
    if error_id is not None:
        new_response_data["error_id"] = error_id
    ...
    response.data = new_response_data

return response
```

And here it is, I have the error response format I was looking for. Thanks to all of you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved using a middleware issue.

I would recommend you to build a custom middleware. So the custom middleware can help you to create the response as per your need. Just plug the middleware in your django application.

You can read more about it in [this blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html) or [this blog](https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/what-are-middlewares)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and references! Yes I could use a middleware for such purpose, but by reading the rest_framework doc about [custom exception handling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling), it seems exactly designed for what I was looking for.

Comment: Cool. I was unaware about it. let me have a look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a **Custom Exception** class as,

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
from rest_framework import status


class CustomAPIException(ValidationError):
    """
    raises API exceptions with custom messages and custom status codes
    """
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail, status_code=None):
        self.detail = detail
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
```

and use in views as,

```
from rest_framework import status


def my_view(request):
    if some_condition:
        error_msg = {
            "error": "To enjoy this feature, go pick one of our pay offer!",
            "error_id": "no_unlimited_access"
        }
        raise CustomAPIException(error_msg)
```